# Calculus: How do you solve this double sequence as its limit approaches infinity?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do you solve the series below?

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\space\sum_{k=1}^{n}\space(2+\frac{3}{n}k)^2\space(\frac{3}{n}) $$

This question is a multiple choice question, and the choices are:
(A) 0
(B) 1
(C) 4
(D) 39
(E) 125

I had initially thought this was an infinite series question, but Thomas Andrews pointed out that this is a double sequence instead. I do not think double sequences are on the [AP Calculus BC curriculum](http://media.collegeboard.com/digitalServices/pdf/ap/ap-calculus-course-description.pdf) but I would also like to know how to solve them as well.

Thank you!

Comment: You mean $n \to \infty$, right?

Comment: How DOES one solve a series?

Comment: This looks like a Riemann Sum to me...  Are you familiar with the methods of solving them?

Comment: Yes I do mean $$n\rightarrow \infty$$

Comment: The question asks for the exact sum of the series.

Comment: Technically, this isn't an infinite series.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What do you mean?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am likewise interested in why you would not consider this an infinite series

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen The terms vary when $n$ varies. An infinite series starts with a sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ and the series is $\sum a_i$. The above is a double-sequence $a_{k,n}$ - it depends on $k$ and $n$- and the terms $b_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k,n}$ are not called a series because the first term in the sum of $b_1$ is not the same as the first term in $b_2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ooohhhhh I did not know that! Thanks for the insight/clarification!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Good to know! I've found myself avoiding the phrase to describe such series in the past as I've been told it is incorrect, but was never told why.

Comment: One does not **solve** a series, rather, one *evaluates* it or, being less breif, *evaluates the series' limit*.

Comment: The main reason to make the distinction is that techniques for series only really work for my definition of "series." There are other techniques for this sort of limit. @GumpyCede

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[2+\frac{3}{n}k]^2\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)$$
We first remember that
$$b\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)$$
If we adjust the sum we get
$$\frac{3}{n}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[2+3\frac{i}{n}\right]^2$$
And we now transform this to
$$3\int_0^1[2+3x]^2 dx = \color{red}{39}$$

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1. Expand and take limit. The answer will be 39
2. Use integration. This will be equal to $3\int_0^1(3x + 2)^2 dx = 39$

I will type out the steps after a while.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(2+3\frac kn\right)^2\frac3n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}3\int_0^1\left(2+3x\right)^2dx=\left.\frac13(2+3x)^3\right|_0^1=39$$

Answer (score 0):

Before taking limits, your sum is

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \dfrac{12}{n} + \dfrac{36 k}{n^2} + \dfrac{27 k^2}{n^3} \right) $$

Using the formulas

$$ \eqalign{\sum_{k=1}^n 1 &= n\cr
            \sum_{k=1}^n k &= \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\cr
            \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 &= \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\cr}$$
this simplifies to 
$$ \dfrac{78 n^2 + 63 n + 9}{2 n^2} = \dfrac{78  + 63 n^{-1} + 9 n^{-2}}{2}$$
so the limit as $n \to \infty$ is $78/2 = 39$.